# square root of vector in R

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R. Struggling to solve the question below.

> Create a new R function getRoot() that will provide square root of any
>   number. If the number is negative it should return ‘not possible’.
>   Demonstrate your function such that it produces the following outputs.
>
> getRoot(c(4,-4, 9, -16))=2 ‘not possible’ 3 ‘not possible’

I wrote the following code:

```
"getRoot" <- function(x){
    res <- as.vector(x)
    if(res < 0) {
        cat("not Possible")
    }else return(sqrt(res))
}

getRoot( c(4,-4,9,-16))
[1]   2 NaN   3 NaN
```

What would the probable solution for that? Thanks.

Comment: I think your teacher is playing a trick on you. In R, vectors cannot be mixtures of numeric and character types. Or ...  perhaps you need a new teacher????

Comment: This is a very bad requirement for an R function. The name of the function is horrible, the fact that the function already exists in R is ignored and that it returns a `character` vector is horrible. Don't do this excercise. You won't learn anything.

Comment: changing your if-else to `ifelse(res < 0, "not Possible", sqrt(res))` would "work"

Comment: @rawr It will return a text vector though, no numbers. It will also produce warnings. It may be the best version for practical purposes, as it is very clear and short (one-liner that does not really need a function around it). I think, you should make it an answer. I do, however, not think, that it is optimal for teaching purposes. Pupils should avoid producing warnings, but obviously you can argue about that and come to differing results. If you make it an answer, you get at least my upvote.

Comment: Thanks all. I have got the idea to answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible, to return a vector `c(4, 'not possible', 3, 'not possible')` as such a vector does not exist. All elements in a vector must be of the same type. Off course you can output numbers an texts together. This is a simple exercise that can be solved in a number of ways. For teaching purposes, I propose the following, where the two problems are divided into two functions in a very functional manner:

```
getSingleRoot <- function(x){
  if(x<0){
    cat("not possible ")
    return(NaN)
  }
  else{
    cat(sqrt(x))
    cat(" ")
    return(sqrt(x))
  } 
}

getRoot <- Vectorize(getSingleRoot)

a <- getRoot(c(4, -4, 9, -16))
```

Other good solutions could make use of a `for` Loop, of `Map`, of `ifelse` or `sapply`, on `sqrt`already being a vectorized function and so on. Ìf this is homework, it depends on what you have already learned.